# What compiler will be chosen by meson.get_compiler('c') on a system with multiple C compilers?

Tags: c, meson-build

Given a meson-based project where `meson.build` contains the following line:

```
cc = meson.get_compiler('c')
```

How does `meson.get_compiler('c')` pick a compiler on a system with multiple C compilers?  At the time of writing this question, the reference manual does not provide much detail, only...

> Returns a compiler object describing a compiler.

Please note I am not trying to force meson to use a specific compiler.  Rather, I am trying to understand how this line in `meson.build`, *as it is currently written*, will function.

Comment: https://mesonbuild.com/howtox.html

Comment: @HansPassant There doesn't seem to be anything there that answers the question.

Comment: I would expect it to look in standard executable directories until it finds a compiler, and use the first one it finds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows it tries icl, cl, cc, gcc, clang, clang-cl, pgcc; on Linux it tries cc, gcc, clang, nvc, pgc, icc. That's after it looks for the value of $CC and whatever is in your cross or native file. [See the code here.](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/blob/master/mesonbuild/compilers/detect.py#L152-L193)